# How do I get Top Left & Bottom right longitude and latitude value for my MapView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

this is my code i'm trying to get display for coordinates , here I'm looking for top left and bottom right long & latitude values but its not working any one suggest me any modifications or any another method to get coordinates ..

```
    public class GpsoverlayActivity extends MapActivity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        MapView map;
        MapController mc;
        GeoPoint gp;
        //Projection projection ;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            map=(MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapView);
           mc=map.getController();
           mc.setCenter(gp);
            mc.setZoom(20);
            Projection proj = map.getProjection();
            GeoPoint topLeft = proj.fromPixels(0, 0);

            GeoPoint bottomRight = proj.fromPixels(map.getWidth()-1, map.getHeight()-1);

            Double topLat = topLeft.getLatitudeE6()/1E6;
            Double topLon = topLeft.getLongitudeE6()/1E6;
            Double bottomLat = bottomRight.getLatitudeE6()/1E6;
            Double bottomLon = bottomRight.getLongitudeE6()/1E6;

        }
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        myLocationOverlay.disableMyLocation();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
    }
```

here this is My LOgCat

```
12-23 11:26:50.264: W/dalvikvm(390): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/gpsoverlay/emigos/GpsoverlayActivity; (6)
12-23 11:26:50.264: W/dalvikvm(390): Link of class 'Lcom/gpsoverlay/emigos/GpsoverlayActivity;' failed
12-23 11:26:50.275: D/AndroidRuntime(390): Shutting down VM
12-23 11:26:50.285: W/dalvikvm(390): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
12-23 11:26:50.285: E/AndroidRuntime(390): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
12-23 11:26:50.456: E/AndroidRuntime(390): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.gpsoverlay.emigos/com.gpsoverlay.emigos.GpsoverlayActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gpsoverlay.emigos.GpsoverlayActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@44e83900
12-23 11:26:50.456: E/AndroidRuntime(390):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
12-23 11:26:50.456: E/AndroidRuntime(390):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
12-23 11:26:50.456: E/AndroidRuntime(390):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
12-23 11:26:50.456: E/AndroidRuntime(390):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
12-23 11:26:50.456: E/AndroidRuntime(390):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-23 11:26:50.456: E/AndroidRuntime(390):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-23 11:26:50.456: E/AndroidRuntime(390):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
12-23 11:26:50.456: E/AndroidRuntime(390):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-23 11:26:50.456: E/AndroidRuntime(390):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-23 11:26:50.456: E/AndroidRuntime(390):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
12-23 11:26:50.456: E/AndroidRuntime(390):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
12-23 11:26:50.456: E/AndroidRuntime(390):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-23 11:26:50.456: E/AndroidRuntime(390): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gpsoverlay.emigos.GpsoverlayActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@44e83900
12-23 11:26:50.456: E/AndroidRuntime(390):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
12-23 11:26:50.456: E/AndroidRuntime(390):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
12-23 11:26:50.456: E/AndroidRuntime(390):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
12-23 11:26:50.456: E/AndroidRuntime(390):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
12-23 11:26:50.456: E/AndroidRuntime(390):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2409)
12-23 11:26:50.456: E/AndroidRuntime(390):  ... 11 more
12-23 11:26:50.645: I/dalvikvm(390): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
12-23 11:26:50.825: I/dalvikvm(390): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-23 11:26:54.515: I/Process(390): Sending signal. PID: 390 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to extends MapActivity instead of Activity. All the class and interface for map are available into the MapActivity and MapView only work within the MapActivity.

After overlay initialization you are using mapv object I didn't find this one.

```
myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapv); // here mapv object used instead of map I think
mapv.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay);
mapv.postInvalidate();
```

Comment: yaa....i tried, here im using oly one activity as Mapactivity but i need lang&lattitude values disply in o/p

Comment: I think you going wrong way as you get the bottom right value that will give you the map control width and height and I think you need to bound the value from map what the map actually display like current area